# Efficient way to extract formatted data in C

Tags: c, string

I have a string of the form 
`[S{i,j} : this is stack overflow]`
I want to extract `i,j` and `this is stack overflow` in two separate strings.
sscanf will not work here as strings to be extracted can have spaces.

Can anyone please suggest an efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the string cannot contain the ending square bracket, you can absolutely use `sscanf()`:

```
int i, j;
char text[128];

if( sscanf(input, "[S{%d,%d} : %127[^]]", &i, &j, text) == 3 )
{
  printf("got it all!\n");
}
```

For more information about the somewhat lesser known conversion specifier `[`, see for instance [this manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf). Basically, the conversion `%[^]]` means "all characters except a closing square bracket, it's a special form of the syntax using both negation (`^`) and doubling the closing bracket to include it in the set of negated characters.

**UPDATE** If you really mean "in two separate strings", then of course the above is wrong since it parses out the numbers into `int`-type variables. To get the pair as a string, use something like:

```
char ij[32], text[128];

if( sscanf(input, "[S{%31[^}]} : %127[^]]", ij, text) == 2 )
{
}
```

Comment: Change `%S` into `S` and it will work fine: http://ideone.com/ZAe1N4 (I haven't downvoted your answer).

Comment: The first bit was supposed to be a string -- `[S{%10[^}]}` should work.

Comment: @Crozin Thanks, that `%` before the `S` was a typo; fixed now.